# Repair electronic board of food dryer

Tags: triac, repair

I recently bought a used food dryer. The heater would not turn on, everything else seems to be working fine. I took it apart to investigate.

I found a burned resistor in the path between the bt139 triac and the display board (holding some IC). Will fixing the resistor be sufficient? I know it was a 680-ohm resistor from the fan’s triac.

The triacs both have the same resistance readout so I assume they are good.

The seller claims the thing was working. Any idea why it would blow up?

The cold heating spiral has a resistance of 120 ohms. Is that potentially too low? It's just a long spring.

[image: burned resitor]

[image: simple schematics]

[image: back]

[image: front]

Comment: Need schematics

Answer (score 2):

Resistors don't fry themselves like that.

There is, or was, some other fault, and too much current went through the resistor, and it burnes up.

If you change the resistor, it will likely burn up too, if some other component is at fault.